# PHP / Laravel, how to connect to a local samba drive

Tags: php, laravel, samba, smb

I am using PHP and Laravel framework to call an image from a samba drive on my company's local network, so the images are located at smb://192.168.12.XX and we do have to enter our credentials in the network. How can I use PHP or the Laravel filesystems.php to call the file?

```
<img src="smb://192.168.12.33/images"/>
```

I just need the file to be pulled and display correctly.

Comment: Personally, I would mount the samba on the OS and then use Laravel's File Storage to access the files. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

Comment: Thanks, does Laravel support SMB? I could not find any documentation on it.

Comment: You can use a php smb client library. Some of those libraries only support smb1 which is deprecated and unsafe to use. I also recommend to cache the images you want to show.

Comment: If you mount it as a mount point with the OS then you won't need PHP to do anything other than read the file

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use this PHP module: https://github.com/eduardok/libsmbclient-php